# RxJava Custom event subscriber

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I have stream of events such as RequestIssuedEvent, DataType1Event, DataType2Event etc. I am looking for an operator which would catch the event down in a chain and stop the propagation, otherwise would let the event to go throw the rest of the chain. (Something like subscribOnThisTypeOfEvent()).

Is there an operator in RxJava which would subscribe on custom events?

Comment: Have you looked at the filter operator?

Comment: It stops the propagation through the chain in case it doesn't fulfill the condition.

Comment: The way I parsed your post, it should do what you want. Maybe I didn't understand your post.

Comment: You could use `groupBy`, or `publish(selector -> {selector.ofType}) ` to split your observable.